# What IK solution is used in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, inverse-kinematics

i'm not so good in math, not as good as someone could, but i still need to implement IK for one of my game, i'm interested to know about which solution is mostly used, and if possible, which one will work well with C# execution time, and unity environment. I don't want to implement every of the solution to test them one by one, i really don't have enough time or even knowledge for that.
(as far as i know, there is jacobian method, and cyclic descent, and some others, i don't want to make advanced physics simulations, but just have something good enough for C# games, which would still look smooth.)

Do someone could tell what solution is used in Unity? 
https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/InverseKinematics.html

what solution should i choose for a C# engine, or a C# game?

Answer (score 0):

Final IK is a really good IK for Unity

https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/14290